# How do I put my table in the top right-hand corner of my screen?(I am in html)

Tags: html

I want to put an some animation on my screen so I got a really cool idea and the programmed it. I have it ready and now I put it in a table(i really love tables) to create a "bordered" effect. It now sits in the bottom corner of my screen. i have used align="right" and gotten this far. Vertical-align or valign="top" are not doing anything. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the actual markup, e.g. possible containers like a `div` where the table is located, one approach can be using absolute positioning (just using the selector `table` as example, better use a class):

```
table
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynfkskgc/)

To display the table to the right, you can use float:

```
table
{
  float:right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kop03qwq/)
but question because of missing markup / CSS in the OP is, why the table is currently displayed at the bottom. In case this is a misunderstanding and it's not the table that you want to position, but content in a tablecell - `<td>` - you can consider to update this in your question to avoid confusion.